# Springboot application not using the correct .properties file

Tags: java, spring-boot, environment-variables, spring-data

I have a simple Springboot app that can be ran with the command: `./mvnw spring-boot:run`. This works fine if I put the URI to my database inside of the `application.properties` file but the problem is that this file is used by Heroku, and is not meant for my local use.

So I came across a Stackoverflow answer that said I could simply make another `.properties` file but name it `application-dev.properties` and then when I run my app, the correct `.properties` file will automatically be chosen when I set the active profile to `dev`.

So I tried this by doing the following:

1. Make the `application.properties` file use the environment variable from Heroku since this is the `.properties` file I do NOT want to use locally.
2. I created a `.properties` file called `application-dev.properties` that has this line in it:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://MY_NAME:MY_PASSWORD@springbootcluster.v1maw.mongodb.net/Employees?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

3. I run the app like this: `./mvnw spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=dev`
4. The app fails with a ton of different errors because it is trying to use the `application.properties` file and not the `application-dev.properties` file

Part of the error message:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'employeeRepo';
```

[ERROR MESSAGES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1XUh.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-Dspring.profiles.active` is setting the `spring.profiles.active` system property in the JVM that's running Maven, not the JVM that's running your application. To fix the problem, use the `spring-boot.run.jvmArguments` system property to configure the arguments of the JVM that is used to run your application:

```
./mwnw -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Dspring.profiles.active=dev"
```

Alternatively, there's a property specifically for setting the active profiles which is slightly more concise:

```
./mvnw spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev
```

You can learn more in the [relevant section of the reference documentation for Spring Boot's Maven plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.x/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#run).

Comment: [In my case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75847080/generate-swagger-json-yaml-from-spring-boot-application) it seems that Spring is still using the wrong `.properties` file.