# Generate Swagger JSON/Yaml from Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, maven, openapi

According to [this](https://springdoc.org/plugins.html), the `springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin` should generate the OpenAPI description files during runtime. Hence, this is why I have an `openapi` profile in my `pom.xml`:

```xml
<profile>
    <id>openapi</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <profiles>
                        <profile>openapi</profile>
                    </profiles>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
                <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.2</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

As such, I am adding `-P openapi` to the `mvn` command line arguments:

```bash
$ mvn clean install -P openapi
```

Which activates the Maven `openapi` profile from the `pom.xml`

Note theat I am setting `<profile>openapi</profile>` in the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` again, in order to run the Spring Boot application with the Spring-profile `openapi` as well. This is what should cause Spring Boot load the `application-openapi.yaml` instead of the default file.

From the logs I can tell that the profile appears to be active:

```
[  restartedMain] com.example.server.Application  :  The following 1 profile is active: "openapi"
```

but I can see in my error logs that it's trying to acces the environment variable `JDBC_DATABASE_URL` from the `application.properties` file - something that is not present in the `application-openapi.properties` file:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, ${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.<init>(DriverDataSource.java:110) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.initializeDataSource(PoolBase.java:326) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.<init>(PoolBase.java:112) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
```

Clearly, something is going wrong here and I'm not sure what exactly.

Comment: Profile-specific configuration files are loaded in addition to "normal" configuration files. In other words, with the `openapi` profile active, both `application.properties` and `application-openapi.properties` will be loaded. When the same property is defined in both places, the profile-specific configuration takes precedence. Does that explain the behavior that you are seeing?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Yes, thanks a lot. I eventually figured that that's what happening indeed.  Thank you :)